# ASP.NET/PHP: How to pass session variable from PHP to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, php, session-variables

I was wondering if it's possible to pass a session coming from PHP by simply clicking a link from the PHP site

from PHP site:

> [Click here](http://www.123company.com?id=1)

and then the ASP.NET site (www.123company.com) will get the value of id=1 and use it to validate an existing function.

Is it possible? Comments and suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand... you're passing the value using the querystring so.... What do you need the session for?

Comment: @Claudio: thanks for the hat tip. already used querystring: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/QueryString.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My guess is no. You will have to maintain session in DB and when you navigate to the ASP.net site, it should access the same db to retrieve the session.

Comment: @Yogendra: is there a way to get the existing URL of the ASP.NET site so I could just parse it to get the 'id=1' part?

Comment: I think since you are passing the value in query string, you should be good.

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? I guess using DB is the only option to pass session variables between ASP and ASP.Net and php and asp.net. 
If query string is used, the value can be retrieved using the headers or the forms. I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

- Create an .ASPX page which accepts parameters via the QueryString.
- Have your .ASPX page do some validation to check that it is your PHP script that is accessing it (i.e. not Joe Public on the internet). Then have it set each of the QueryString parameters as session variables in the normal way.
- When you want your PHP page to be able to set a value in the ASP.NET session, fire off a simple HTTP request to your special ASPX 'bridging page'. It will convert the querystring variables you've passed to it via the QueryString into Session values.

Providing the user maintains the current browser window, when navigating from your PHP script to your ASP.NET site, you should fine that does just the trick...